# Rearranging values mixed up in incorrect columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm cleaning a dataframe and have this column `Description` that I would like to split into 4 separate new columns(Type, Stories, Bedrooms, Bathrooms).
The column contains entries mainly in this format: `Type: Detached; Style: 2-Story; 3 Bedrooms; 2 Bathrooms` which is the correct format I want every entry in the column to have. The problem is some entries are mixed up, e.g.

`1 Bathroom; 2 Bedrooms;  Type: Bunaglow; Style: 1-Story;`

or

`3 Bedrooms; Type: Detached;  Style: 2-Story; 2 Bathrooms;`

both of which are in the incorrect order and do not follow the format above.

I already carried out a .str() split to create the 4 new columns but I have no idea how to deal with these mixed-up entries.

I found a solution online that somewhat works and implemented it into my dataframe but the problem with it is I have to manually specify each and every mixed-up entry and my dataframe contains over 950 rows. Is there any sort of way I could define a criteria for my column 'Description' and implement a check that if certain entries do not match up with the criteria they should be sorted correctly and then updated to the data frame, or can I tackle this in a better way than manually specifying each individual row?

**Code to manually sort one of the mixed-up entries, the problem here is I have to specify out of which of the 4 new columns I want the individual values swapped around for**

```
m = df1['Type'] == '2 Bathrooms'
mp = {'Type': 'Bathrooms', 'Bathrooms': 'Type'}
df1.update(df1.loc[m].rename(mp, axis=1))
df1
```

[Original Dataframe Before Str Split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY6p2.png)


**String Split**

```
df1[['Type','Stories','Bedrooms','Bathrooms']] = df1['Description'].str.split(';', expand=True)
df1 = df1.drop('Description', axis=1)
```

[Current State of Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6txmb.png)

**df1.head().to_dict()**

```
  1: '2016-01-07',
  2: '2016-01-10',
  3: '2016-01-10',
  4: '2016-01-10'},
 'Price(€)': {0: 638740.0, 1: 541330.0, 2: 376039.0, 3: 546446.0, 4: 494491.0},
 'Location': {0: 'Brookville',
  1: 'Brookville',
  2: 'West End',
  3: 'West End',
  4: 'West End'},
 'Year Built': {0: 2011, 1: 2019, 2: 1964, 3: 2013, 4: 2004},
 'Size(sq ft)': {0: 1839, 1: 1551, 2: 1073, 3: 1216, 4: 1687},
 'Description': {0: 'Type: Detached; Style: 2-Story; 3 Bedrooms; 2 Bathrooms',
  1: 'Type: Detached; Style: 1-Story; 3 Bedrooms; 2 Bathrooms',
  2: 'Type: Terraced; Style: 1-Story; 3 Bedrooms; 1 Bathroom',
  3: 'Type: Detached; Style: 1.5-Story; 2 Bedrooms; 2 Bathrooms',
  4: 'Type: Detached; Style: 2-Story; 3 Bedrooms; 2 Bathrooms'}}
```

Comment: Can you provide access to the actual data or show  few rows of the input dataframe as text?

Comment: Apologies, updated it now with the data frame text

Comment: No need to apologize.   Thanks for providing text.

Answer (score 1):

Try using .str accessor,`extract`, regex, and named capture groups like this:

```
regstr = 'Type: (?P<Type>.*); Style: (?P<Style>.*); (?P<Bedrooms>\d+) Bedrooms; (?P<Bathrooms>\d+)'
df.join(df['Description'].str.extract(regstr))
```

Output:

```
  Date of Sale  Price(€)    Location  Year Built  Size(sq ft)                                        Description      Type      Style Bedrooms Bathrooms
0   2016-01-03  638740.0  Brookville        2011         1849  Type: Detached; Style: 2-Story; 3 Bedrooms; 2 ...  Detached    2-Story        3         2
1   2016-01-07  546330.0  Brookville        2009         1551  Type: Detached; Style: 1-Story; 3 Bedrooms; 2 ...  Detached    1-Story        3         2
2   2016-01-10  376039.0    West End        1963         1073  Type: Terraced; Style: 1-Story; 3 Bedrooms; 1 ...  Terraced    1-Story        3         1
3   2016-01-10  506446.0    West End        2013         1206  Type: Detached; Style: 1.5-Story; 2 Bedrooms; ...  Detached  1.5-Story        2         2
4   2016-01-10  494491.0    West End        2004         1687  Type: Detached; Style: 2-Story; 3 Bedrooms; 2 ...  Detached    2-Story        3         2
```

Comment: Hi Scott, I've been working on using the capture groups like the one you gave above but I'm not sure on whether it's possible to pass multiple of these groups to `.str.extract` all at once and then join them all to the data frame. Would this be within the scope of the `extract()` function or would I have to extract each group individually?

Comment: @umba Here, I am extract four named groups at once, Type, Style, Bedroom, and Bathrooms.  After those columns are extracted, then you can join back to the original dataframe as I have shown here.  Please clarify your question if you need further guidance.

Comment: I was referring to the groups where the order is incorrect/mixed up. Such as in one instance for row 949 the entry is `2 Bathrooms; Style: 2-Story; 3 Bedrooms; Type: Detached` which does not follow the `regstr` format above and so is returned as `NaN` for each of the 4 new columns in the dataframe

Comment: Oh...  if that is the case, then you'll need to do them individually and join them to the dataframe.   I don't think there is a way to handle multiple orders using `extract`.